# Test spring repository with pageRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, repository

Im have repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    List<Product> findAllByPriceBetween(BigDecimal from, BigDecimal to, PageRequest pageRequest);
}
```

In liquibase im just create table:

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset <sniklz>:<create-products-table>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products
(
    id bigint auto_increment,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    price decimal      not null,
    CONSTRAINT product_pl PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

--rollback DROP TABLE products;
```

then im try to test my repository:

```
@DataJpaTest
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase (replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class ProductRepositoryTest  {
    @Container
    static MySQLContainer<?> database = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8")
            .withDatabaseName("springboot")
            .withPassword("springboot")
            .withUsername("springboot");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setDataSourceProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry propertyRegistry) {
        propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url", database::getJdbcUrl);
        propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", database::getUsername);
        propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", database::getPassword);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    @Sql("/scripts/init_four_products.sql")
    void shouldReturnProductPriceGreaterThan1200() {
        List<Sort.Order> order = new ArrayList<>();
        order.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "price"));
        Sort sort = Sort.by(order);
        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 10, sort);
        List<Product> acutal = productRepository.findAllByPriceBetween(BigDecimal.valueOf(1200),
                BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE), pageRequest);
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, acutal.size());
        Assertions.assertEquals("iPhone XI", acutal.get(0).getTitle());
    }
}
```

in `/scripts/init_four_products.sql` im just create som products:

```
INSERT INTO products (title, price) VALUES ("iPhone 8", 700);
INSERT INTO products (title, price) VALUES ("iPhone 9 ", 800);
INSERT INTO products (title, price) VALUES ("iPhone X", 1000);
INSERT INTO products (title, price) VALUES ("iPhone XI", 1200);
```

But have error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: At least 3
> parameter(s) provided but only 2 parameter(s) present in query.;
> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 3
> parameter(s) provided but only 2 parameter(s) present in query.

did not find any useful information at google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters):

> The infrastructure recognizes certain specific types like `Pageable` and
> `Sort`, to apply pagination and sorting to your queries dynamically.

With that being said, you should replace `PageRequest` with `Pageable` in the `ProductRepository` method:

```java
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    List<Product> findAllByPriceBetween(BigDecimal from, BigDecimal to, Pageable pageable);
}
```

`Pageable` should be instantiated as follows:

```java
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10, sort);
```